# How to get two columns data into one column using case in sqlserver2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to get sales amount of 2019 into a separate column called new, if sales of 2018 = 0.Here my code for your reference

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(sp.Telephone,'No Sales Employee'),
    od.CardCode,
    od.CardName,
    Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '2' then od.DocTotal else 0 end) as Sold2018,
    Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '1' then od.DocTotal else 0 end) as Sold2019,
    (select od.DocTotal where c.U_ItemStatus = '2' ) as new
FROM
    ORDR od
Left Join OSLP sp
    On od.SlpCode=sp.SlpCode
left join RDR1 a on a.DocEntry = od.DocEntry
left join OITM b on b.ItemCode = a.ItemCode
left Join OITB c on c.ItmsGrpCod = b.ItmsGrpCod
Group By
    sp.Telephone,
    od.CardCode,
    od.CardName,
    c.U_ItemStatus,
    od.DocTotal
```

Comment: Please include the current output along with what you want the output to actually look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `CASE` statement and note that you need to use the entire expression for `Sold2018` in the condition and not the `alias`

```
CASE WHEN Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '2' then od.DocTotal else 0 end) = 0 
     THEN Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '1' then od.DocTotal else 0 end)
     END  AS New
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(sp.Telephone,'No Sales Employee') ,
    od.CardCode,
    od.CardName,
    Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '2' then od.DocTotal else 0 end) as Sold2018,
    Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '1' then od.DocTotal else 0 end) as Sold2019,
    CASE WHEN Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '2' then od.DocTotal else 0 end) = 0 THEN 
              Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '1' then od.DocTotal else 0 end) END as new
FROM
    ORDR od
Left Join OSLP sp
    On od.SlpCode=sp.SlpCode
left join RDR1 a on a.DocEntry = od.DocEntry
left join OITM b on b.ItemCode = a.ItemCode
left Join OITB c on c.ItmsGrpCod = b.ItmsGrpCod
Group By
    sp.Telephone,
    od.CardCode,
    od.CardName,
    c.U_ItemStatus
```

or

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Sold2018 = 0 THEN Sold2019 END as new 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(sp.Telephone,'No Sales Employee') as Telephone,
        od.CardCode,
        od.CardName,
        Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '2' then od.DocTotal else 0 end) as Sold2018,
        Sum(case when c.U_ItemStatus = '1' then od.DocTotal else 0 end) as Sold2019     
    FROM
        ORDR od
    Left Join OSLP sp
        On od.SlpCode=sp.SlpCode
    left join RDR1 a on a.DocEntry = od.DocEntry
    left join OITM b on b.ItemCode = a.ItemCode
    left Join OITB c on c.ItmsGrpCod = b.ItmsGrpCod
    Group By
        sp.Telephone,
        od.CardCode,
        od.CardName,
        c.U_ItemStatus
) AS T
```

Comment: 1st one is okay,but 2nd answer gives and error called "No column name was specified for column 1 of 'T'.
" .

Comment: it needs an alias for the first column.it fixed.